# flutter context and mediaquery use in another class

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

How can I do this class without GetX framework?

I tried to use context extension and received `The instance member 'context' can't be accessed in an initializer error`.

Comment: Please [do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).  [Edit] your question and copy-paste it into the question itself in between \`\`\` the code \`\`\`.

Answer (score 0):

use [LayoutBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/LayoutBuilder-class.html). From there you can get the remaining width and height, and use them to make breakpoint decisions.  From there, use flex widgets in Rows and Columns for individual widget layout.

Comment: bro i didnt want this please answer according to my question

Comment: It precisely answers your question.  You should not bake the width and height values in as static constants.  They can change over the execution of the program -- even devices can be rotated to landscape mode.  LayoutBuilder at runtime is your best choice.

Answer (score -1):

**I tried this to get what you want** :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Dimentions {
    final BuildContext context;
    Dimentions(this.context);
    double get containrHeight => MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2;
    double get containrwidth => MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 3;
}
```

**and use like this:**

```
Container(
          width: Dimentions(context).containrwidth,
          height: Dimentions(context).containrHeight,
          color: Colors.black38,
        )
```

[this will render like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i29Nw.png)

**Hope this helps you**

Comment: yes i did that too

Comment: have you found any better way?